# Outlook add-in not available for IMAP on windows

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have an add-in that works fine on Outlook for mac but not on windows for IMAP (Gmail) accounts.

Is the setup different to how the IMAP is configured on MAC and Windows?

```
Mac Version - 16.41 (20091302)
Win Version - 16.0.13127.20402
```

This is an issue because a lot of our users are unable to use the add-in when they have multiple accounts in Outlook on windows (of which most are IMAP - Gmail)

I would have thought it would be other way around where Add-ins would be available on Windows and not on Mac since a lot other things are not supported on Mac within outlook.

[image: Add-ins visible on Mac for IMAP account]

[image: Add-ins not visible on Win for IMAP account]

Are there settings that can be changed to make them available on windows or of anyone knows about this being available in the future?

----------------- UPDATE --------------------

```
Mac Version - 16.42 (20101102)
```

So, this morning 19th Oct, 2020. I got an Outlook Update for mac and as per the screenshot below, you can clearly see that I am using a Google Account (IMAP) and the add-ins are availanle.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to VSTO add-ins or Web Add-Ins?

Comment: This is for web add-ins

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Added a comment to the answer. I did come across that article and was the reason I added asked this question. Mac client and Windows client behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Web Add-Ins are only supported on Outlook accounts connected to an Exchange server. Further documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-requirements

Comment: Yes, it is connected to an exchange server. The outlook client is connected using an outlook account and another gmail account was added to it as an IMAP. If the requirements are to always be connected to exchanged, it does not explain why the web add-ins are available on Mac and not windows.

Comment: Let me clarify. Web add-ins will only work for Exchange accounts. These Exchange accounts have to be connected to Outlook via the default protocol (MAPI over HTTP). If the Exchange account is connected to Outlook via another protocol (IMAP, POP, etc), web add-ins won't work. Also, web add-ins don't work for non-Exchange accounts. It sounds like you have an Outlook profile with multiple accounts : 1 Exchange account (MAPI over HTTP) and 1 GMail account (IMAP). Web add-ins will only work for the Exchange account, not the GMail one. Is this the same configuration for Mac Outlook?

Comment: The configuration is the same on Mac. Sorry, but it still does not explain why web add-ins are available on Outlook for Mac. See the original question with updated screenshot. All our employees on Outlook for Mac using GSuite account (IMAP) can use web add-ins but not the ones on windows.

Comment: Add-ins are supported in Outlook on Mac on Gmail accounts if you use cloud cache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/exchangedev/announcing-add-in-support-for-gmail-accounts-in-mac-outlook. For Outlook on Windows, add-ins are not supported for Gmail accounts. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Add-ins are supported in Outlook on Mac even with IMAP, but not on Windows. Why? No idea, but it is what it is.