# Outlook web add-in: attachment id is malformed after Oct 2020 Mac update

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

Received an update on Outlook for Mac this morning. 19th Oct, 2020 and since, IMAP emails with attachments is having issues downloading them via our add-in.

Looked up the issue and we are getting `Id is malformed`. This did not happen before the update. On further inspecting, found that the `restUrl` is empty in `Office.context.mailbox` and when this happens, we fallback to `ewsUrl`, which is great because we have a fallback, but now EWS throws the mailformed Id error.

The Id now looks like `id: "362{00000000-0000-0000-C842-010000000000}"`, I've got no idea what type of Id this is, it used to be a base64.

Are there change logs for this? or how do we deal with this Id if there is no RestUrl and EWS can't recognise this Id.

[image]

Comment: Are you using new Mac UI or old one?
What is the current version of outlook that you are using?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT This is in the new UI. Mac Outlook version `16.42 (20101102)`

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have fixed the bug where restUrl was coming as empty and the fix should be available in next monthly build. Depending on the release channel a customer is on, getting an updated build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for this, will check the release channel and make sure it's updated. Anyway, this will solve the issue of us getting the correct restUrl but in certain cases we still have to download items via EWS, cases such as downloading itemAttachment, will EWS accept the new format of ID. Also, my other question about web add-in on windows for IMAP is still unanswered -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379666/outlook-add-in-not-available-for-imap-on-windows

Comment: The new format of attachmentId will not work with EWS. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point. We will update this thread once the bug is fixed.

Comment: Thanks, what about the other question mentioned above. It’s been ignored and I need to find a solution for IMAP options on windows.

Comment: We have fixed the issue with attachmentId. Depending on the release channel a customer is on, getting an updated build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.